# How to adjust tab order in Eclipse Mars using WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

Just have a quick question about Eclipse Tab Order.

I'm designing an interface that accepts input from a user (about topics such as their first name, last name, phone number, etc) using Eclipse Mars WindowBuilder.

I'm trying to adjust the tab order in the property section and it's allowing me to change the order of which tab I want to go after the other.

However, when I run the program, the tab order is not the case, and it reverts back to a randomized tab order.

I cannot seem to figure out why, and I've looked online. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: What tabs are you talking about

Comment: tabs as in switching from one JFormattedTextField to another. I want to make it a specific order when i hit the tab button. Think of it as if you were signing up for an account for a website. You'd fill in your first name, then hit TAB, and you'd be placed in the Last name field. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the Design tab of WindowBuilder, select getContentPane().  There is a "Tab Order" property that you can use to adjust the order of all the components in your pane.  Click on the elipsis (...), reorder the items the way you want and uncheck those that you don't want.  Click OK.  There is also a Tab Order item listed under "System" in the Palette. Selecting this will display the tab order in the Windowbuilder canvas as numbers in little yellow squares that are shown next to the component, so you can tell exactly what's happening.
[Here's an example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rsZt.gif)

Answer (score 1):

In the Design tab of WindowBuilder, select the FRAME or INTERNALFRAME, and below find the "tab order" property, and adjust your components accordingly.
OR
Add this to your code,

```
setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(
                new Component[] { 
JTextField1, JTextField2, JTextField33, JComboBox2, JComboBox3, JComboBox54,   JButton1 , btnSave }));
```